# Generating array in range a to z then aa to zz then aaa to zzz and pick any random character from it

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to generate an array in range `a` to `z` then `aa` to `zz` then `aaa` to `zzz`, and pick any random character from it.

Suppose there is `[a, b, c, .., z, aa, bb, .., zz, ..., aaa, bbb, ..., zzz]`. I want to pick any random character from it like `rand(10)`.

We can generate a range like `('a'..'z')`, but I don't know how to achieve the above.

Comment: Not strictly what you're after but same end result `('a'..'z').to_a.sample * rand(1..3)`

Comment: @SagarPandya: beautiful. This is a valid answer, I think. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I really wanted to use `rand('a'..'z')` somewhere :(

Comment: What are those variables `a`, `b`, etc? That doesn't sound like a good idea. Also, what do you mean with "character"? And do you really not want for example `ab`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following

```
array = []

3.times do |i|
    array += ('a'..'z').collect { |e| e * (i+1)}
end

array.sample
```

Comment: sorry I was misunderstood question, now updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh,  above work perfectly but I will follow `('a'..'z').to_a.sample * rand(1..3)`

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
(1..3).flat_map {|n| ('a'..'z').map { |char| char * n } }.sample
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no one magic construct for this, I'm afraid. But it's not very hard to get what you want by combining smaller simpler ruby concepts: ranges, turning ranges to arrays, `map`, building strings by multiplication, concatenating arrays. Take a look:

```
one_letter = ('a'..'z').to_a # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
two_letters = ('a'..'z').map { |c| c * 2 } # => ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", "nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", "zz"]
three_letters = ('a'..'z').map { |c| c * 3 } # => ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt", "uuu", "vvv", "www", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]

combined = one_letter + two_letters + three_letters

random_element = combined.sample # => "pp"
```

Comment: I think you can get away with only having to use the `three_letters` array here. Then doing something like `three_letters.sample[0..rand(4)]`

Answer (score 1):

Given a range of letters `r` and a range `m = 1..n`, where `n` is a positive integer (“maximum multiple”), let `S` be the set of all strings of the form `s*t`, where `s` is in `r` and `t` is in `m`, `*` being the method [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-2A). Then the probability of drawing the element `s*n` in `S` at random is

```
P[s in r and t in m] = P[s in r|t in m] * P[t in m]
                     = P[s in r] * P[t in m]
                     = (1/r.size) * (1/n)
```

`P[s in r|t in m]` is read “the probability of `s` in `r` *given* `t` in `m`“. `P[s in r|t in m] = P[s in r]` because the two events are independent.

We therefore can draw a random element `s*t` by drawing random elements `s` in `r` and `t` in `m`.

```
def doit(rng, mult)
  rng.to_a.sample * rand(1..mult)
end

doit 'a'..'z', 3 # => "zz"
doit 'a'..'z', 3 # => "eee"
doit 'a'..'z', 3 # => "j"
doit 'a'..'z', 3 # => "k"
```

Comment: `(1..mult).to_a.sample` -> `rand(mult) + 1`?

Comment: Thanks, @Sergio. Good suggestion. I see your return value was also `’pp’`. Mind meld?

Comment: Actually, the best way was shown by @sagarpandya in the comments above, `rand(1..3)`. I always forget this form.

Comment: Better yet, @Sergio! I’m not sure if I forgot that too or never knew it.

Comment: uh-oh, now your code is broken, in multiple places actually.

Comment: @Sergio, can you fix it? I wrote this on a phone and am falling asleepzzzzz

Comment: sure, no problem :)

Comment: (If my basic prob knowledge is correct). A random sample from the full array has prob 1/78 is equivalent to this solution which selects a random letter with prob 1/26 _and_ a random number from 1 to 3 with prob 1/3, which gives (1/26)*(1/3) == 1/78.

Comment: Also `rand(97..122).chr` is an alternative to creating the full array of letters, but less semantic and readable.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev. Why not `rand(rng)` in place of `rng.to_a.sample`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: try it. :) `rand` doesn't accept string ranges.

Comment: `[*rng]` instead of `rng.to_a` looks quite nice too:)

Comment: Thanks, @Sergio. Do you know why we don't have a method `Range#sample`?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ("A".."ZZZ").to_a
puts array.sample
```

First line creates the array, second gets a sample from it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but this should work:

```
# Create an array of a to zzz
word_array = ('a'..'zzz').to_a

# select certain items from the word array
word_array.select! do |word|
    # Convert each word to a char array
    char_array = word.each_char.to_a

    # Check if there are no duplicates in this array
    char_array.uniq.count == 1 
end

# pick a random item
word_array.sample
```

Comment: Take a look at all these wasted cpu cycles and ram 

Answer (score -1):

Generate a random number below 26**3, take its digits in base 26, add 97 to each digit to obtain an ASCII value and form a string.

```
p rand(26**3).digits(26).map{|d| (d+97).chr}.join  # => "wfo"
```

Comment: it gives error `undefined method `digits' for 15171:Fixnum`

Comment: `digits` method was introduced in Ruby 2.4.0 .

Comment: "wfo" is apparently not among the desired possible outputs, judging by the question and other answers and the acceptance of one of them. But it's good to see I'm apparently not the only one who finds that odd.